# What happens when SIGKILL is sent to a multi-threaded process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sigkill

Regarding how signals work internally I have read this post [kill - How signals work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/how-signals-work-internally). However, in that post the special signal, namely **SIGKILL** was not explained.

This [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) only specified **SIGKILL** and **SIGSTOP** cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored, but not more.

Will anyone please describe in more detail about how **SIGKILL** worked, specifically on Linux 2.6 or higher:

1. **The setup (infrastructure) inside the kernel**. **SIGKILL** is not catchable, but how is this implemented
2. **What actions were taken for that receiving process**. It may be the parent or the kernel who took control over that **KILL**ed process. How were its child processes, its running threads, its resource (phyical memory pages, open file handles etc) got freed/recycled? What about the task structs in scheduling world?
3. **What's the interaction between SIGKILL and multi-threading? Will there be any contention?** In a multi-threaded server instance, worker threads allocate resouces and run in a loop to serve requests. Will there be a chance that one thread is doing its job while its resource got freed/recyled by the kernel, shall I say.

Comment: Go to http://elixir.free-electrons.com and search for `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I think SIGKILL causes the termination of the process in entirety. for more details this link will help you: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?399918-pthread_kill-and-SIGKILL